# Como alinhar uma imagem dentro de um componente Alert Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

Preciso alinhar a imagem horizontal e Verticalmente no centro do alert, mas não estou conseguindo. Eu tentei usar um padding de 100 (como exemplo) para demonstrar que a imagem se movimenta... Eu gostaria apenas de alinhá-la. Como eu faço isso?

```
<div id="alert-dicas" role="alert" class="alert alert-warning alert-icon alert-dismissible">
    <button id="btn-close-dicas" aria-label="Close" class="close" type="button">
        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
    </button>
    <i class="icon fa-lightbulb-o" style="font-size:32px; padding:100px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <h4>Dica</h4>
    <p>
        Logo abaixo, você visualizará algumas informações de conexão com o banco de dados. <br />
        Para garantir a segurança, nós armazenamos o seu arquivo de Bakup em nosso servidor, mas aconselhamos que você faça download e guarde-o em um local seguro para utilizá-lo quando for preciso.<br />
        Lembre-se sempre: Faça backups periódicos, pois se o sistema for atacado por vírus e outras ameaças, seus dados poderão ser perdidos e voce só poderá recuperá-los se tiver um backup recente!
    </p>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se eu remover o padding, fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: qual versão do bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap v3.3.7

Comment: Vc falou que quer no centro, mas na verdade é pra ficar onde está o quadrado vermelho correto, centrando só na vertical?

Comment: Isso. Verticalmente no centro.

Comment: Eu joguei um padding de 100 para a imagem se movimentar e ir para a posição da imagem. Se eu remover o padding, a imagem fica alinhada no canto superior colada com a a palavra Dica.

Comment: Eu atualizei o post... Desconsidere o padding... Acho que ele não será útil... Observe a segunda imagem... É assim que fica... Gostaria apenas de descê-la e alinhá-la verticalmente no centro e não deixá-la colada com o texto. Para isso precisaria de um alinhamento horizontal centro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara primeiro vc tem que colocar `position relative` no `box` para poder colocar `positon absolute` no `icon` e controlar as coisas. Depois vc da um `padding-left` no `box` para empurrar o texto para direita dando espaço para o `icon`. Depois vc da um `top` de 50% e `translateY(50%)` no `icon` para ele ficar alinhado sempre na vertical. *Não precisa de `padding` no ícone não.*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima:

```css
#alert-dicas {
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
.icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

<div id="alert-dicas" role="alert" class="alert alert-warning alert-icon alert-dismissible">
  <button id="btn-close-dicas" aria-label="Close" class="close" type="button">
      <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
  </button>
  <i class="icon fa-lightbulb-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <h4>Dica</h4>
  <p>
      Logo abaixo, você visualizará algumas informações de conexão com o banco de dados. <br />
      Para garantir a segurança, nós armazenamos o seu arquivo de Bakup em nosso servidor, mas aconselhamos que você faça download e guarde-o em um local seguro para utilizá-lo quando for preciso.<br />
      Lembre-se sempre: Faça backups periódicos, pois se o sistema for atacado por vírus e outras ameaças, seus dados poderão ser perdidos e voce só poderá recuperá-los se tiver um backup recente!
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado @hugocsl! Funcionou 200%!

Comment: @MasterJR sem problemas meu caro